# What is a perfectly separable topological space?

Tags: general-topology

A perfectly separable topological space is a space with a perfectly dense countable subset. This definition is stronger than the definition of separability.

As an example, if $(X,\geq)$ is a perfectly separable ordered set, then, there exists subset $A$ st for all $x>y$, exists $a$ in $A$ such that $x\geq a\geq y$.

I worked hard to find clear definition for "perfect dense set" and "perfect separable" with no luck. What is a clear definition and how does it stronger than the conventional separability?

Comment: where did you find these terms in the first place?

Comment: "Perfect" comes in at least two completely different meanings:  *every closed set is $G_\delta$* and "*has no isolated points*. I assume, here you mean the latter?

Comment: A dense set $D$ must contain all isolated points $I(X)$ of the space $X$, and, of course, they are isolated in the subspace as well. Hence, $I(X) \subset I(D)$. Under some mild separation property ($T_1$ or even $T_D$) we have equality. Hence, a $T_D$ space is perfectly separable, iff it is perfect and separable.

Comment: @Ulli Great explanations! It seems like "connected" is a special case of "has no isolated points".

Comment: Might be, I completely misunderstood your question: since "perfectly dense" is not a standard notation, as far as I know, but you are not defining it, I just *assumed*, it means the most obvious thing (in my opinion), namely perfect (here: no isolated points) and dense subset. If this is not the case, you should definitely answer M W's question. Or at least say, that you cannot remember, where you saw it. As stated, and without any reaction, it is quite confusing!

Comment: And what is exactly your question? Are you asking for a *reference* for these "definitions"? If you are looking for a "clear definition", which unclear definition do you have in mind? And, even more important, where did you find it?

Comment: @Ulli Yes you are right I am looking for a clearer topological definition. The unclear definition I have in mind is in the example of ordered space above.

Comment: @dodo Is this your own made up terminology, or do you have a reference for it somewhere?

Comment: @PatrickR It is not self-made but I have no reference for now

Answer (score 1):

So, let's try another guess, what your question might be:

Let $(X, \le)$ be a linearly ordered set with the order topology.
$A \subset X$ is called $\le$-dense (in $X$), if
for all $x, y \in X$, such that $x < y$, there is an $a \in A$ such that
$x \le a \le y$.
(Sorry, I prefer to think of $\le$ rather than $\ge$.)
Then you are looking for a topological characterizaton of $\le$-dense.

Is this your question?
For me it's not clear, whether you first want to define
"perfectly dense" and then "perfectly separable" as having a countable perfectly dense subset.
Also your example is confusing, since on the one hand you say "perfectly separable", but on the other hand, you don't require $A$ to be countable.
As it is stated, it is fulfilled by *any* (linearly) ordered set.

Moreover, what is a "perfectly separable *ordered set*"?
Just a linearly ordered space, which has a countable, perfectly dense subset (assuming, of course, the latter already being defined)?

Anyway, according to my above guess, $\le$-dense cannot topologically be characterized:

Of course, in $\mathbb Q$ (with the usual order) the complement of any finite set is $\le$-dense.
Now consider $X = \mathbb Q \setminus (0,1)$. $X$ with the order topology is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$. But $X \setminus \{0, 1\}$ is not $\le$-dense in $X$.